# question about smtp server and nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am using the nodemaielr to try to send email.
sendMail.js :

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'hostmailer.com',
});

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'company@example.com',
    to: 'xxx@x.com',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello!'
};

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent', info.response);
    }
});
```

and I always get this error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.208.78.36:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.208.78.36',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

it seems the firework issue of my company. The host('hostmailer.com')refused any connection.

so I planned to create a smtp server by using smtp-server

I download the code from the github link  `https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server`
and run the file server.js in which I set the host `127.0.0.1` and port `2525`.
in the sendMail.js file, I changed the host and port to `127.0.0.1` and `2525` separately. Although there is no error while running, I still can not get email from the server.

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my company's firewall issues. 
I can't get connect to the SMTP server of my company because my local ip is in blacklist of our company. 
I need to contact with tech support team of my company to whitelist my ip then I can connect to the server.